Compile dml for simics
I am following the instructions after creating a dml module with the command bin/project-setup --device=simple_device and everything is ok. The next step say I have to compile using gmake o gmake simple_device in the root of the project. I cant find how to make work that 'gmake', installed it from here gnuwin32 but the terminal shows not knowing the gmake command, I am on Windows 11 but testing also in ubuntu 24.04 machine

The same winlibs toolkit as used in this question: Problems building dmlc on Windows should work here.
I.e., build the device using bin\make.  Alternatively, use CMake, follow the steps in the "Using Cmake with Simics" document.  CMake takes a few more commands to set up, but it builds much faster.
